# How to send LinkedIn Invitation in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using this jar (custom-linkedin-j-android.jar) for invitation on LinkedIn in android  and my code is below which I am using

```
client.sendInviteById(pp.getId(), "App", "invitation ", toekn.toString());
```

but it's not working.

Anyone have idea how I can send invitation on LinkedIn in android.